# How do i switch between screens in swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

This has been asked before but I would like **clarification**, I'm new to java coding (sort of, started coding last month) and would like to know simply **how can I switch between UIs in one JFrame**, Picture this, a settings menu, How do I make it in one JFrame window instead of just make a new window with all the settings, If you don't get it, ask for clarification.

Comment: You could use a JTabbedPane, or you could use a JPanel with a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a frame (JFrame) and, for example, two panels (JPanel). Initially you embed panel A inside frame, when you want to show panel B then call the method `showPanelB()`

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    PanelA panelA = new PanelA();
    PanelB panelB = new PanelB();
    
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    public MyFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        showPanelA();
        
    }
    
    public void showPanelA() {
        getContentPane().add(panelA, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    
    public void showPanelB() {
        getContentPane().add(panelB, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

}

class PanelA extends JPanel {
    // Panel implementation
}

class PanelB extends JPanel {
   // Panel implementation
}
```